# how to search and delete a specific node in a linked list in c++

Tags: c++, list, nodes

using structures, I created a structure named **file** that point to the next file, i successfully managed to create files and display them but i have not been able to write a function that deletes a specific file with a certain name from the linkage ,the headfile is a file pointer pointing to all files.

```
struct file
    {   
    string filename;
    file *nextfile;
    };

typedef file *fileptr;   

void deletespecific_file(fileptr &headfile)
    { 
        while (headfile != NULL)
            {
            if(headfile->filename=="filea")
                {
                fileptr temp = headfile;
                delete temp;    
                }
            headfile = headfile -> nextfile;
            }
    }
```

Comment: When you delete `temp`, you're also deleting `headfile` (they point to the same data).

Comment: @cmbasnett thanks ,would you mind showing me what you think should be done ,quite stack here!